# In ASP.NET MVC how can I pass a String variable to the _Layout.cshtml view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC how can I pass a String variable to the _Layout.cshtml view; ViewBag and ViewData don’t seem to work, is there another/prefered way?

Best Wishes,
Yends

Comment: ViewBag and ViewData should be fine. Can you show how you are going about it?

Comment: I am trying to pass data from a controller that is not the home controller to the _Layout.cshtml view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ViewBag/ViewData work fine. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Hello World";
    return View();
}
```

and inside `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div>@ViewBag.Message</div>
```

Comment: I am trying to pass a mock authorisation type from the HTTP-Post Method LogOn inside AccountController to the _Layout.cshtml, this method won't work, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Yends, why it wouldn't work? Suffice to set the ViewBag variable in your POST action to whatever value you want to send. Also in your layout you could test whether the value has been set and only then use it.

Comment: My colleague is actually the one working on this and is getting very confused, I will get him to make his own account and continue this thread. Thanks for your input.

Comment: continued: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403349/asp-net-mvc-3-sending-string-from-http-post-method-to-layout-cshtml - sorry for the shoddy use of multiple questions